# Property Changed not firing UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding

I'm trying to validate a property object with FluentValidation when that object changes.

```
private Empresa empresa { get; set; }

    public Empresa Empresa{
        get { return empresa; }
        set { 
            if (empresa == value) return;
            empresa = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Empresa");
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string empresa)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Empresa"));
    }
    
    private void EmpresaViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CompanyValidator validator = new();
        this.ValidationResult = validator.Validate(empresa);
    }
```

But when the property changes in the XAML the set doesn't fire

```
  <TextBox Header="Nome Simplificado" 
                         MinWidth="200" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus"
                         TextChanging="TextBox_TextChanging"
                         Text="{Binding Empresa.SimplifiedName, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                         />
```

Does anyone know how to get this working?
(Ps. When I instantiate a new object of that class the event fires).

Comment: You left out important code. Did you register/attach `EmpresaViewModel_PropertyChanged`?

Comment: What is `SimplifiedName`?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, for the first question, yes, I just didn't post that part of the code to don't make it too big to read. SimplifiedName is a property in the Empresa class/model

Comment: The property change registration will probably registered on the `Empresa` object, instead of the Model.

Comment: So, I need to have the INotifyPropertyChanged directly in the class? I've tried that but then I cant validate the data since I need to send an entire Empresa object to validate.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish here, but since you bind to `SimplifiedName` you probably want to handle the `PropertyChanged` event for this property. `Empresa` won't be set when you type something into the `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Property Changed not firing UWP

The problem is that `Text` property binding path is `Empresa`'s property, but not Empresa itself, you just implement `RaisePropertyChanged` for `Empresa` instance, So it only works when Empresa is created for the first time.

And if you want to update `Text`, you need also implement for `SimplifiedName` property.

```
public class Empresa:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _simplifiedName;
    public string SimplifiedName
    {
        get { return _simplifiedName; }
        set
        {
            if (_simplifiedName != value)
            {
                _simplifiedName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SimplifiedName");
            }
            
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**Update Text**

```
private void MyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Empresa.SimplifiedName = "New Value";

}
```